# Ubuntu 12.04 Installer doesn't recognize other OS

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-8

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8 on a Dell Inspiron SE  The installer says I currently have no detected operating systems.  Is it ok to go ahead with the install using the "something else" option and putting Ubuntu on a partition or will it wreck my Windows 8?

Comment: Please specify which version of Ubuntu 12.04 you are using (desktop or server, 32 or 64 bit).

Answer (score 1):

You should shutdown Windows 8.1.

At default setting, Windows 8 is just hibernating.
I think your Win OS is hibernated so the disk is still mounted at the Windows side.
Get in to the power settings and set the appropriate checkbox.
This [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZaZEIadu1U) can be useful.